# Simple file locking wrapper command in C

Tags: c, file, linux, locking, posix

A simple command that wraps another command, locking a file first. It is similar to `flock`, just simpler.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void attemptLock(const char *lockFileName)
{
    int fd = open(lockFileName, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0666);
    if (!fd || flock(fd, LOCK_EX))
        warn("Cannot lock %s", lockFileName);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Not enough arguments.\nUsage: %s LOCKFILENAME COMMAND...\n", argv[0]);
    attemptLock(argv[1]);
    argv += 2;  // Skip our own command name and LOCKFILENAME.
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot execute %s", argv[0]);
}
```

Anything fishy? Bogus? Wrong? Anything that can be improved (besides adding options like `-h`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides reinventing the wheel the things I'm concerned about are:

- the `warn` in `attemptLock`, because if either creating the lock file
  fails, or if you can't get the lock (or the call was interrupted), I
  would expect the wrapper to exit instead,
- the return value of `open`, which might very well be negative, so just
  check for that separately and give an error message for that,
- the return value of `flock`, where you should handle `EINTR` in a loop
  I believe?

Comment: Once again shows how good it is to have code reviewed. The `warn` instead of `err` was intentional because of support for a specific version of *Cygwin* which has issues with successfully locking, but there should at least have been a comment for explaining the unexpected `warn` instead of `err`. And the other two issues that you've found are real bugs. So, thanks a lot!